# Array con Queryselectorall

Tags: javascript, html, css

estoy haciendo un modal con html,css y js. El modal funciona correctamente, pero al usar querySelectorAll traigo 4 elementos que comparten class.
(En la imagen del js se aprecia que uso un array al final de cada variable para seleccionar que elemento de los 4 que traigo abre el modal)
Quisiera que en lugar de hardcodear la posición del array que se va a mostrar, pudiera usar una variable que corresponda al ID de cada elemento.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Soy bastante nuevo con javascript y nunca publique en esta pagina, espero que se haya entendido mi problema lo mejor posible y puedan ayudarme

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. ¿No se abre tu modal?  ¿Tenés más de un modal? ¿ No funciona el ```addEventListener```? Es necesario incluir tu código, la parte que no funciona: tu html modal, y el JavaScript que abre el modal.

Comment: Hola. Ahora estoy pensando como replantear la pregunta para que sea lo mas explicita posible. Funciona el modal la apertura y el cierre del modal. Pero yo tengo 4 elementos html que comparten el modal. Quisiera diferenciarlos a los 4 por id, para eso agregue el [x] pero no logro que el X contenga el valor del id clickeado.